Probabilistic Approach to Weak Goldbach Conjecture
The motavation comes from Circle Method. I saw some results where Heath Brown, Davenport use circle method, and they derive an asymptotic formula for the number of solutions of a homogenous cubic equation inside the box $\mathbf{x} \in [-P,P]^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. The main term is $P^{n-3}$ and the error term is $o(P^{n-3})$. This makes a lot of sense because if we assume that the values of a cubic form is equidistributed, then the range of $C(\mathbf{x})$ for $\mathbf{x} \in [-P,P]^n$ is $O(P^3)$. Thus the probability that the cubic form vanishes is $\frac{1}{P^3}$. Thus asymptotically the number of integral solutions to $C(\mathbf{x})$ is around $\frac{P^n}{P^3}=P^{n-3}$. This is consistent with the main term in the expression, when circle method is applied.
More generally, if one has degree $d_i$ forms for $i=1, 2, 3 \dots k$, then the expectation is $$O(P^{n-d})$$ where $d=\sum_{i}d_i$.
My main question is the heuristics for the representation of a natural number $N$ as a sum of three primes. I tried approaching this but I am overcounting or apparently incorrect. I would appreciate any insights into it.
Considering a natural number $N$, we want to write it as $N=p_1 + p_2 + p_3$, and thus we must have $p_i \leq N$, the chance of $p_1$ being a prime number less than $N$ is $\frac{N}{\log N}$. Simmilarly the chance of $p_2$being prime is $\frac{N}{\log N}$. Thus we have around/approx $\frac{N^2}{(\log N)^2}$ ways to write $N$ as sum of three primes. However its clear that the range of $p_2$ will reduce as soon as we choose $p_1$ to be very large. Morever after we choose $p_1$ and $p_2$, it is not necessarily true that $p_3=N -p_1 -p_2$ is always going to be prime.

do you consider that $a+b+c$ and $a+c+b$ count for 1 or for 2 ?

They count for $2$, Morever I believe that should not be an issue, because we would have a constant factor of $6$.

Choose three primes at random in $[N/100, N]$ so they sum in $[3N/100, 3N]$; exclude the edges (so we are in $[3N/100+cN, 3N-cN]$ for some small but fixed $c>0$) and assume we have a roughly even distribution of the sum of the three primes among the odd numbers there, so we have about $KN^3/\log^3 N$ sums for $3N/2$ or so  numbers, hence each should be written in about $CN^2/\log^3N$ ways - of course this is a bit coarse but it can be refined and is the nub of why the method works for $3$ but not for $2$; see https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/heuristic-limitations-of-the-circle-method/

why did you remove a small neighborhood around the edges, what is the issue if we do not remove it?

If I consider the heuristic for sum of $2$ primes, then following the method you suggested, I am getting about $\frac{CN}{\log^2 N}$ ways to write a natural number as sum of two primes. I am not sure what I am supposed to see this as. I will look into the link you suggested.
